# "View Page Source" shows html fully expanded

Tags: html, web-hosting

This is weird, never have seen this happen. At first I thought it must be some setting in FireFox, but it happens in every browser. So possibly it has something to do with a setting on the hosting web server.

Usually when I right click on a web page and view the html source, I see the lines that link to css, font, and script library files.

But on this one website I'm working on, the entire library for each linked file shows.

Here's the head section of the actual code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Wayne's Wax - Industrial Class Waxing System for the Airline,Automotive, RV, Theme &amp; Amusement Park, and Do It Yourself Markets</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Slabo+27px' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Just+Another+Hand' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,100italic,300,300italic,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic,900,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<link href="<?php echo PATH; ?>css/main.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="<?php echo PATH; ?>css/menu.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo PATH; ?>js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="<?php echo PATH; ?>perfect-scrollbar/css/perfect-scrollbar.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo PATH; ?>perfect-scrollbar/js/min/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo PATH; ?>perfect-scrollbar/js/min/perfect-scrollbar.min.js"></script>
<!-- ... and so on, and so forth... -->
</head>
```

But if you view the html source, that's not what you see. You see something like,

```
<style type="text/css" style="display:none">@font-face {
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Slabo 27px'), local('Slabo27px-Regular'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/slabo27px/v3/PuwvqkdbcqU-fCZ9Ed-b7fk_vArhqVIZ0nv9q090hN8.woff2) format('woff2'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/slabo27px/v3/PuwvqkdbcqU-fCZ9Ed-b7RsxEYwM7FgeyaSgU71cLG0.woff) format('woff');
}

</style>

<style type="text/css" style="display:none">@font-face {
  font-family: 'Just Another Hand';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Just Another Hand'), local('JustAnotherHand-Regular'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/justanotherhand/v7/fKV8XYuRNNagXr38eqbRfzpTO3zq7FUe5pJUVhf_ntc.woff2) format('woff2'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/justanotherhand/v7/fKV8XYuRNNagXr38eqbRf8DbBFScDQWNirGEA9Q9Yto.woff) format('woff');
}

</style>

<style type="text/css" style="display:none">@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  src: local('Roboto Thin'), local('Roboto-Thin'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/2tsd397wLxj96qwHyNIkxPesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff2) format('woff2'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/vzIUHo9z-oJ4WgkpPOtg1_esZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff) format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Roboto Light'), local('Roboto-Light'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/Hgo13k-tfSpn0qi1SFdUfVtXRa8TVwTICgirnJhmVJw.woff2) format('woff2'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/Hgo13k-tfSpn0qi1SFdUfT8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff) format('woff');
}
```

etc., etc.

Nothing is broken, but it's not the way I like to see html source rendered. I want to click the linked library within the source view, and then go to the css or script page. I don't really want to see all 18,000 lins of html source laid out in one view.

This is the site where this is happening: [client website](http://wayneswax.com/2015/)

**UPDATE:** The source code looks normal if I get to the website by clicking the link I provided in this question. That at least explains why nobody else is seeing what I was seeing.

Comment: Not seeing anything that you refer to. Works fine for me.

Comment: There's probably a load optimization/caching plugin installed that throws some of the resources into the page.

Comment: I also don't see those style tags in the source.

Comment: I also just see the regular HTML source. This issue doesn't seem to be reproducible.

Comment: UPDATE: It looks normal when I click the link I gave.